# Mapreduce function to calculate in degree and out degree and show sum using java

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am trying to sum the in degree and out degree for a set of data.
Here is the sample data:

```
Source  Target

1        2  
2        1  
3        1  
2        3
```

So the expected output is:

```
ID     In degree   Out degree  
1       2            1  
2       1            2  
3       1            1
```

How can this be achieved with mapreduce Java and print out the results in a single line.

Comment: why outdegree for 1 is 2?

Comment: hi, sorry that's my mistake, it should be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option involving one MR job: 
Assuming that the original dataset looks like `[node1,node2]`:

-mapper reads original dataset and emits triples `[node1,out]` and `[node2,in]` for every line

-reducer gets triples from mapper in form of `[key,label]`, computes the outdegree and indegree by counting "out" labels and "in" labels separately per key and outputs them in form of `[key, indegree, outdegree]`

Implementation would look similar to below (assuming that `node1` and `node2` in your dataset are separated by space and also assuming that the dataset contains distinct pairs only):

Mapper:

```
public class YourMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        String line = value.toString();     
        String[] line_spl = line.split(" ");

        String node1 = line_spl[0];
        String node2 = line_spl[1];

        Text node1_txt = new Text(node1);
        Text node2_txt = new Text(node2);
        Text emit_out = new Text("out");
        Text emit_in  = new Text("in");

        output.collect(node1_txt, emit_out);
        output.collect(node2_txt, emit_in );

      }//end map function


}//end mapper class
```

Reducer:

```
public class YourReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

         int count_outs = 0;
         int count_ins  = 0;

            while (values.hasNext()) {

              Text value = (Text) values.next();

              String value_str = value.toString();

              if(value_str.equals("out"))
                 count_outs++;
              else
              if(value_str.equals("in"))
                 count_ins++;  

            }

            Text out = new Text(count_ins + " " + count_outs);              
            output.collect(key, out);

    }//end reduce function

}//end reducer class
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am unable to print 3 columns , as its just key value pair, can you please suggest the best way to do it?

Comment: yes, it is key-value pair) hence in mapper you may for example emit [key, Text] by concatenating the values like [node1, "node2_out"] and [node2, "node1_in"]. Then in reducer, you use "Iterable<Text> values" as an argument and parse every value (i.e. split by delimiter "_" to check if it is for indegree or outdegree) and then do counting

Comment: Can you please provide a dummy example of how this can be done?

Comment: @testAccount in the reducer, `context.write(key, value1+" "+value2)`... That'll output "three columns", however of course multiple "columns" could exist as part of each value variable

Comment: @testAccount see the approximate implementation in my updated answer